# T4MVC unable to start transformation run creation process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, t4mvc

When I try to run the template file, it doesn't do any new transformations other than replacing the T4MVC.cs file with `ErrorDebuggingTemplate` as its only contents and Visual Studio shows "Unable to start transformation run creation process" as the only error.

I haven't modified this T4 template at all. It's the same file we've used for the past two years and it debugged fine under VS 2013 and VS 2015. This year I only had the option to install VS 2017 and it results in the crash.

The version of T4MVC we have installed is 3.14.2. Updating it to the latest will result in having to update ASP.NET and several other libraries that we don't exactly want to update at this time. How can I get T4MVC to work under these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with VS 2017 and it was fixed with an update just a couple weeks ago: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/93087/view.html